# If $A\cup B=A\cup C$ and $A\cap B= A\cap C$, prove that: $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> If $A\cup B=A\cup C$ and $A\cap B=A\cap C$, prove that $B=C$.

**My attempt:**
$$A\cup B= A\cup C$$
$$n(A\cup B)=n(A\cup C)$$
$$n(A)+n(B)-n(A\cap B)=n(A)+n(C)-n(A\cap C)$$
$$n(B)=n(C)$$
$$B=C$$.

Is this correct?Or, do we have any other alternatives?

Comment: Euler would be proud

Comment: @mrnovice, what do you mean?

Comment: No, it's not correct. Firstly, the sets weren't specified as finite sets. But even if they were known to be finite, all you proved is that the sets $B,C$ have the same number of elements.

Comment: @quasi, what is the correct method?

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is rather unclear. What do you mean by $n(A)$ for example.

The proof is rather straight forward however by showing equivalence between $x\in B$ and $x\in C$. You do this by separating the cases where $x\in A$ and $x\notin A$.

If $x\in A$ you have $x\in B\cap A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$ and $x\in B\cap A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$, but yoo already have $x\in B\cap A \Leftrightarrow x\in C\cap A$ so it follows that $x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in C$.

If on the other hand $x\notin A$ you have $x\in B\cup A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$ and $x\in B\cup A \Leftrightarrow x\in B$, but yoo already have $x\in B\cup A \Leftrightarrow x\in C\cup A$ so it follows that $x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in C$.

Since you have $x\in A$ or $x\notin A$ you have $x\in B\Leftrightarrow x\in C$ universally which means $B=C$.

---

You can reformulate this using set algebra notation:

Let $U$ be a superset of $A$, $B$ and $C$ (for example $U=A\cup B\cup C$):

Since $A\cup B = A\cup C$ we have $(U\setminus A)\cap(A\cup B) = (U\setminus A)\cap(A\cup C)$. Since $(U\setminus A)\cap A =\emptyset$ we have:

$$(U\setminus A)\cap B
= ((U\setminus A)\cap A) \cup ((U\setminus A)\cap B) 
= (U\setminus A)\cap(A\cup B) \\
= (U\setminus A)\cap(A\cup C) = (U\setminus A)\cap C$$

Now we have that $(U\setminus A) \cup A \supset U$, since $U$ is a superset of $A$, $B$ and $C$ we have $(U\setminus A) \cup A = U$ and $B = U\cap B$ so we have:

$$B = U\cap B 
= ((U\setminus A) \cup A) \cap B 
= ((U\setminus A) \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)
= ((U\setminus A) \cap C) \cup (A \cap C) = C$$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is not correct, as you only proved that both $B$ and $C$ have the same *number of* elements, not that they have the same elements. To prove that $B=C$ you have to prove that $x\in B$ if and only if $x\in C$.

Answer (score 2):

First we show $B \subseteq C$.

It suffices to show $x \in B \implies x \in C$.

Suppose otherwise. Thus, suppose $x \in B$ but $x \notin C$. Then

\begin{align*}
&x \in B\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in A \cup B\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in A \cup C&&\text{[since $A\cup B = A \cup C$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in A&&\text{[since $x \notin C$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in A \cap B&&\text{[since $x \in B$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in A \cap C&&\text{[since $A\cap B = A \cap C$]}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x \in C\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction.

It follows that $x \in B \implies x \in C$, hence $B \subseteq C$, as claimed.

By analogous reasoning (or by symmetry), we get $C \subseteq B$.

Therefore $B=C$.

Answer (score 2):

By assumptions, $\color\orange{A\cup B=A\cup C}$ and $\color\red{A\cap B=A\cap C}$. Since $B\subset (A\cup B)$ and $C\subset(A\cup C)$, we get
$B=B\cap(A\cup B)$ and $C=C\cap(A\cup C)$, respectively. Hence,
$$\begin{align}
B&=B\cap (\color\orange{A\cup B})\\
&=B\cap(\color\orange{A\cup C})\qquad\text{then use distributive law to get}\\
&=(\color\red{A\cap B})\cup(B\cap C)\\
&=(\color\red{A\cap C})\cup (B\cap C)\qquad\text{again use distributive law to get}\\
&=(\color\orange{A\cup B})\cap C\\
&=(\color\orange{A\cup C})\cap C\\
&=C.
\end{align}$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/%ce%98%ce%a3%ce%a6gensan, from which relation did you get, $$B=B\cap (A\cup B)$$?

Comment: @Leonhard Euler Notice that $B \subseteq (A \cup B)$ and thus intersecting this with $B$ gives back $B$.

Comment: @Leonhard Euler Draw in a  Venn Diagram and you will see it easily. Anyway, the comment of @ stud_iisc is a good start to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose that $B\neq C$, and give a $x$ in both equalities. You will find a contradiction, analize the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Write: $B=((A \cup B) \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$ and similarly for $C$.

Comment: How did you write that $B=..$?

Comment: @Leonhard Euler Notice that $(A \cup B) \setminus A$ gives the elements of $B$ excluding the common elements between $B$ and $A$ i.e., equivalently this is $B \setminus A$. $B$ is written such a way to use the given hypotheses efficiently.